# concatenate nested macro result

Tags: c++, macros, variadic-macros, boost-preprocessor

I have the following set of macros:

```
macro_1(p1)
macro_2(p1, p2)
macro_3(p1, p2, p3)
etc.
```

Now, I want to make another generic macro that will evaluate to the previous ones, and I am trying to do that like so:

```
#define macro_x(...) macro_ ## BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_SIZE(__VA_ARGS__) (__VA_ARGS__)
```

The idea behind that is that `BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_SIZE(__VA_ARGS__)` evaluates to the correct count of parameters, which will then turn to the correct macro.

But, unfortunately I just found out that `BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_SIZE()` will be evaluated after it will be concatenated to `macro_`, resulting in the unwanted code `macro_BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_SIZE`.

Is there a way I can first evaluate `BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_SIZE` and then concatenate to `macro_`?

Comment: Holy moly! Variadic macros! D: me likes the sound of it :)

Comment: Just use `BOOST_PP_OVERLOAD`. Your current problem can be fixed by using `BOOST_PP_CAT` instead of `##`, but the macro's already made so no point in not just using it.

Comment: @chris - Thanks, but please write it as an answer so I can mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is already done for you with `BOOST_PP_OVERLOAD`:

```
#define macro_x(...) BOOST_PP_OVERLOAD(macro_, __VA_ARGS__)(__VA_ARGS__)
```

The reason yours doesn't work is because the concatenation needs a delay in order for the macro to expand. While easy to define your own, `BOOST_PP_CAT` already exists:

```
#define CAT_(a, b) a##b
#define CAT(a, b) CAT_(a, b)
```